# focus on UITextField then select UIButton xcode

Tags: xcode, uitableview, uibutton, uitextview

I want to get when I focus on UITextField then change image of UIButton in front of UITextField in UITableview. It can be possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can get notified when your `UITextField` gets focussed by implementing the `UITextFieldDelegate` method `textFieldDidBeginEditing:`.

```
textField.delegate = self;
```

After you implement this method, get the reference of the correct `UIButton` and change the required image like this.

```
-(void)textFieldDidBeginEditing:(UITextField *)sender{
    [yourButton setImage:newImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

Comment: my button is in UITableView by dynamically created. Please check my question.

Comment: To get the reference of the dynamically created button in the table view, you could use tags. And then in the didBeginEditing method, you can obtain the button from your tag.

Comment: Why not updating your answer as showing complete example?